# New tab function with WKWebView storyboard window

Tags: objective-c, macos, storyboard, window, nsdocument

I did the change to storyboards in my macOS app (Objective-C).
Here it comes to a big problem with the NSDocument new tab function.

```
- (WKWebView *)webView:(WKWebView *)webView createWebViewWithConfiguration:(WKWebViewConfiguration *)configuration forNavigationAction:(WKNavigationAction *)navigationAction windowFeatures:(WKWindowFeatures *)windowFeatures{
if (!navigationAction.targetFrame.isMainFrame) {
    // Diagnose
    // NSLog(@"Diagnose new Tab: %@",navigationAction);
    // New Tab
    [[NSDocumentController sharedDocumentController] openUntitledDocumentAndDisplay:YES error:nil];
    // Load webView
    [_webView loadRequest:navigationAction.request];
}
return nil;}
```

The new tab will be generated but the webView doesn't show the website which should be opened in the new tab. In the new tab will be the current website duplicated. I'm helpless...

PS: There are no navigation errors.

Comment: What do you mean by the NSDocument new tab function? `openUntitledDocumentAndDisplay` is available in macOS 10.4+. You create a new document and don't use it.

Comment: The problem is not the creation of the new tab. The problem ist the usage of the webView in the new tab. The WKWebView request can‘t be performed. Do I have to select the webView in the new tab in an other way like I did it?

Comment: The `_webView` of which document should load `navigationAction.request`?

Comment: The `webView` of the new tab.